SPSS Mixed-effects model moderation interaction output
in my conceptul model I want to study if Agreeableness trait (Agree IV: likert scale) effects initial offer in a negotiation (Offer DV: any number between 5 and 15), and how does trust moderate this relationship (Time: no trust=1, trust=2)
I used the mixed effects model in SPSS as my data is within subjects, where each respondent was asked to input an offer in a 'no trust' scenario, and later also in a 'trust' scenario (repeated measures).
I also included Neuroticis, Openness, Extroversion, Conscientiousness, and Gender as covariates.
As fixed effects I included all covariates and Agreeableness, as well as the interaction between Time and Agreeableness (I assumed this reflects the moderation, correct?)SPSS set up
I got the following output: SPSS Output
Can someone help me interpreting the output to answer my research question? I am not sure where to look for significance in this case.

Welcome to Stack-Overflow! As your question is not about programmig, it is off topic here - you should post this question HERE instead.
